# How to send data from ThingSpeak to ESP-8266 (Arduino) using ThingHTTP?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I have made an Arduino kit that acts as a weather station. It sends sensors data (DHT11 & LDR) to the ThingSpeak web server.

Now I want to perform some actions based on the data on the ThingSpeak server (like if temperature exceeds a limit turn on the fan, etc).

I've searched and I found that there's a React app on ThingSpeak, which will trigger events if data exceeds some values.

The problem where I got stuck is that I want to send a signal from the ThingSpeak web server to my ESP8266 (Arduino) to turn on/off the device connected to a relay on Arduino.

I've figured out that there's also a ThingHTTP feature which sends HTTP requests. But I don't know how to send requests/signals to my kit to perform some actions.

I've already spent 2 months building this project, and now I'm stuck in the last part. Please give your valuable suggestions and solutions.

Comment: Why do you think you need to bounce the value via ThingSpeak when the Arduino already knows what is going on, since it has send those values to ThingSpeak in the first place?

Comment: You raised a valid point! Yes we can burn such code which will perform action according to the sending values but It'll be considered as hard coding and will result into more problems !! Because we've 110 nodes (Arduino kits) and suppose for some reason we've to change the threshold of temperature data for performing some relevant action, then we'll have to burn the modified code again to all the 110 kits. We are thinking to control all these devices from 1 place ( web app). Thanks for your response. Looking forward for your suggestion.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

For sending information to/from Arduino best option is MQTT. It's lightweight and very simple to use.

While your Arduinos are using MQTT to send info and receive commands (like changing thresholds), your Web server has access to the same information in real time. You can format it and present it in any way you like, without any Arduino participation.